# SwiftUI: Need nested function to finish downloading URL before rest of function executes

Tags: swiftui, concurrency

I have a nested function `ImageUploader.sendImage(image: image)` that stores an image to Firestore and needs to return a URL for the main function `handleImageSend` to use to store the URL for later use which makes the value of `imageURL` nil. The problem is the rest of the function is executing before `sendImage` is finished storing the image and returning a URL. I have tried using async/await and @escaping to see if that would help, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Any help is appreciated! Code below.

ImageUploader

```
struct ImageUploader {
    static func uploadImage(image: UIImage, userUid uid: String, completion: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        
        let ref = FirebaseManager.shared.storage.reference(withPath: uid)
        
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to upload image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            ref.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Failed to download image URL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                print("DEBUG: Successfully uploaded image: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                
                guard let url = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                completion(url)
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func sendImage(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping(String) -> ()) {
        
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
            let ref = FirebaseManager.shared.storage.reference(withPath: UUID().uuidString)
            ref.putData(imageData) { _ in
                ref.downloadURL { url, _ in
                    guard let url = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                    completion(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChatLogVM with function in question:

```
    func handleImageSend(image: UIImage?) {
        
        guard let fromId = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let chatUser = chatUser else { return }
        guard let image = image else { return }
        
        ImageUploader.sendImage(image: image) { url in
            self.imageURL = url
        }
            
        let document = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("messages")
            .document(fromId)
            .collection(chatUser.uid)
            .document()
        
        print("DEBUG: \(imageURL)")

        let imageMessageData = ["fromId": fromId, "toId": chatUser.uid, "text": imageURL, "timestamp": Timestamp()] as [String : Any]
        
        if !imageMessageData.isEmpty {
            messageIsAnImage.toggle()
        }
        
        document.setData(imageMessageData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
        
        persistRecentMessage()
        
        let recipientDocument = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("messages")
            .document(chatUser.uid)
            .collection(fromId)
            .document()
        
        recipientDocument.setData(imageMessageData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you put the rest of the code inside the callback, like so?

```
func handleImageSend(image: UIImage?) {
        
        guard let fromId = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let chatUser = chatUser else { return }
        guard let image = image else { return }
        
        ImageUploader.sendImage(image: image) { url in
            self.imageURL = url
            
            let document = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
                .collection("messages")
                .document(fromId)
                .collection(chatUser.uid)
                .document()
            
            print("DEBUG: \(imageURL)")
            
            let imageMessageData = ["fromId": fromId, "toId": chatUser.uid, "text": imageURL, "timestamp": Timestamp()] as [String : Any]
            
            if !imageMessageData.isEmpty {
                self.messageIsAnImage.toggle()
            }
            
            document.setData(imageMessageData) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            self.persistRecentMessage()
            
            let recipientDocument = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
                .collection("messages")
                .document(chatUser.uid)
                .collection(fromId)
                .document()
            
            recipientDocument.setData(imageMessageData) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works. For some reason I was set in my head I needed async, but I clearly did not. I ended up putting the `handleImageSend` inside the `sendImage` function and it works as expected!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept my answer 